# ubuntu 18.04 boot up issues

Tags: boot, grub2, mount

I cannot boot into my encrypted partition anymore. every time it says failed to connect to lvetmad or something and then proceeds to try to load but never does. one time I was able to get to my login page but it was frozen after i put in my password, which i had changed earlier in recovery mode. Here is what I get when I type in fdisk.

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x14be4381

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       501758 976771071 976269314 465.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       501760 976771071 976269312 465.5G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I have attempted to change setting to nomodeset but the linux line isn't even there after pressing e in grub menu.

Comment: You can't change FS encryption password in recovery mode. You need to use the initial password.

Comment: yeah I havent forgotten that password, i think i changed the password to my unix username, sorry for the confusion. i know the passcode for the encrypted hard drive it just wont boot anymore.